# How to set G1GC in Play application

Tags: java, playframework, configuration, supervisord

I'm trying to run a play application on Debian, running on Java 8, but I want to change the default garbage collector in the options to -XX:+UseG1GC.

My OS details:

> Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26)

I've tried multiple option combinations and none appear to work.

My command is something like:

```
bin/playapp -mem 1024
```

And I have tried to change it to:

```
bin/playapp -XX:+UseG1GC -mem 1024
```

And...

```
bin/playapp -J-XX:+UseG1GC -mem 1024
```

I've even removed the `mem` variable to see if would work without it in both of the above scenarios and neither are working.

Anyone know how to set the G1GC garbage collector for a Play app running on Java 8?

**UPDATE:**

I should add, for context, that it is run via supervisorctl, where the command in the command is:

```
command=/home/mdmuser/playapp/bin/playapp -mem 1024
```

I tried using -J-XX:+UseG1GC directly from the command line and it seems to work, but it doesn't work when running via supervisorctl configuation.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the colon or the + sign. I've tried escaping them, but that doesn't seem to work either. I've tried encapsulating in double quotes. No luck either :-(

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not actually the syntax at all. It was the fact that when I moved to the G1GC garbage collector, I needed to allocate less memory to the JVM in my virtual machine. I reduced the memory from 1Gb to 512Mb and it then worked fine using the following syntax:

```
command=/home/mdmuser/playapp/bin/playapp -J-XX:+UseG1GC -mem 512
```

Apologies for any time wasted.